# Cant play a video in Processing - runtime exception

Tags: java, opencv, video, processing

I'm trying to write a program for Brownian motion monitoring. The test code looks fine but I can't download the video nor in .avi nor in .mov format from the sketch folder, the window opens but it only shows a grey background. Message from the console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load movie file Video1.mov
    at processing.core.PApplet.die(PApplet.java:3605)
    at processing.core.PApplet.die(PApplet.java:3614)
    at processing.video.Movie.initGStreamer(Unknown Source)
    at processing.video.Movie.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Particles_monitor.setup(Particles_monitor.java:28)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2401)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1557)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:316)
```

I've tried:

- Changing format of the file from .avi to .mov
- Playing a simple .avi video from the web. It worked.
- Googling. It didnt.

Here is the code:

```
    import gab.opencv.*;
import processing.video.*;

 Movie video; 

 void setup() {
   size (640, 480);
   video = new Movie(this, "Video1.avi");
   video.play();
 }

 void movieEvent(Movie video) {
   video.read();
 }

 void draw() {
   image(video, 0, 0);
 }
```

The file size is 51 Mb, 9 min 27 sec length.

Comment: Please remove processing from your tags and add java and opencv

Comment: OK, I ll add Java but why should I remove Processing?

Comment: sorry, you might be quite right with processing ;-)

Comment: Your code says `Video1.avi` but your error message says `Video1.mov`. Which one is it? Do you have a video file with that exact name? Where exactly is it located? Can you post your directory structure?

Comment: Thanks everyone and excuse me for my stupidity, the problem was that the file name is "Video 1.avi", while in my code it was Video1.avi